# Redirección tras borrar archivos y directorio PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código en PHP que al ejecutarlo me borra los archivos que contiene un directorio. La pregunta es, ¿como podría redirigir a otra página tras hacer la operación? He probado con "header('Location: index.php');" pero sin éxito. Muchas gracias.

```
<?php
$directorio = "directorio";
delete_directory($directorio);
function delete_directory($dirname) {
   if (is_dir($dirname)) {
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
      ob_flush();
      flush();
   }
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
           chmod($dirname."/".$file, 0777);
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file) ) {
            if(unlink($dirname."/".$file)){
               ob_flush();
               flush();
            }
            else{
               ob_flush();
               flush();
            }
         }
         else
            delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   return true;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Ya que tu funcion `delete_directory()` te regresa `true` una vez que hayas terminado te recomiendo realizar una validacion ejemplo:

```
 if(delete_directory($directorio)){

   header('Location: welcome/');

 }
```

2.- Estamos diciendo que si la funcion nos retorna verdadero reedirigimos.

3.- No tendrias por que tener problemas con header, te dejo un enlace para que leas mas sobre header:

[header PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Dónde debería colocar tu fragmento de código para que funcione correctamente?

Comment: Cuando mandes a llamar tu funcion. Ahi realizas la validacion que te puse, aunque te recomendaria que  en tu funcion regreses **true** solo cuando se realice la tarea de elmininacion en caso contrario devuelves false